# How to auto load source file on bash startup?

Tags: command-line, bash, ruby

I recently installed Ruby Version Manager (RVM) to make use of the command called compass. Initially it was working find on installation, but now I get a missing error:

```
The program 'compass' can be found in the following packages:
 * libcompass-ruby1.8
 * ruby-compass
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

However to get it to work again, I have to type in this command:

```
source .rvm/scripts/rvm
```

How do I auto load this file when I start up a terminal? I think I need to add it to the `.bashrc` file but I'm unsure what’s the proper syntax to input there.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the `.rvm/scripts/rvm` file is at your home. Use the following command in a terminal,

```
echo "source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm" | tee -a ~/.bashrc
```

It will add the command at the end of your `~/.bashrc` which is non-login interactive shell initialization file. when you open a terminal you get a [non-login interactive shell](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/52402). So the command will be executed every time you open a new shell or terminal and will serve your purpose.

Open a new terminal to see the effect or use the following command in the same terminal,

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: @sourvac, I respect your answer. Doies it function properly for Ubuntu 16,04 and raspian plus raspberry pi 3 ? Thank you.

Comment: @Frank for Ubuntu 16.04 it will surely work. I can not confirm about raspberry pi. If RP has `echo` and `tee` and it uses `~/.bashrc` as bash shell initialization file I see no reason to not function properly.